# AutoCommit did not work with jOOQ 2.6.1 and Tomcat pooling

Tags: java, tomcat, jooq, pooling, autocommit

I use jOOQ 2.6.1 and the pooling from Tomcat ([docs](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html)) and I have set autocommit to true.

```
PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
p.setDefaultAutoCommit(true); 
p.setJdbcInterceptors("org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;" +
                      "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(10);
```

then I created an Apache DataSource object:

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource = new DataSource
dataSource.setPoolProperties(p);
```

and I use the *LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy* from Spring:

```
LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy lazyConnection = new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy(dataSource);
```

From jOOQ 2.6.1 is use the *Factory*:

```
public Factory createFactory() {
    Settings settings = new Settings();
    settings.getExecuteListeners().add(
            "de.si.srv.data.SpringExceptionTranslationExecuteListener");
    return new Factory(dataSource, SQLDialect.POSTGRES, settings);
}
```

if I do for example a select like this:

```
createFactory().select().from().fetch()
```

... jOOQ should close the connection automatically! But jOOQ does not close the connection.. All connections are after some time Abandoned.

Does anybody know a solution for my problem? I want that jOOQ closes the connections automatically! Or should I use an other pooling framework?

Which works better with jOOQ?

Answer (score 1):

There have been quite a few changes and fixes around that area in jOOQ 3.x, the most important one being:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2373

> or should i use an other pooling framework ?

I don't think another pooling framework will help, here.

If you want to continue working with jOOQ 2.6.1 (instead of upgrading to jOOQ 3.2), I guess you might need to either:

- Patch jOOQ and fix this issue
- Handle the `DataSource` / `Connection` lifecycle yourself and pass a `Connection` to jOOQ

Comment: the problem with jooq 3.x ist that we must migrate a lot of things. It would be easier to patch this issue. But i don't know where to start. What should i exactly Patch and where in the Code ?

Comment: I agree, the impact of migrating to jOOQ 3.x might be too big for such an issue. But the various fixes in that area were non-trivial to achieve. Patching them will not be easy. If you want our help to fix this for jOOQ 2.6.x, you might get lucky by [contacting us through the support channels](http://www.jooq.org/support#a=support-custom-engineering), or the [user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jooq-user). It is up to you to assess if this is easier than maintaining the connection lifecycle yourself. Anyway, I think this is out of scope for this Stack Overflow question.

Comment: The most Time it works greate with the Abandoned connections because i have set the options "setRemoveAbandoned(true);setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(10);" and so the connection is returning to the pool. But sometimes i get the following Error:this exc:org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: jOOQ; uncategorized SQLException for SQL ... SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Connection has already been closed.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed." If you know a solution for the "Connection has already been closed" Problem this would help me.

Comment: Let's discuss this on the [jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jooq-user). Please provide stack traces and maybe a simple case to reproduce this issue. This is going to be too much for the little space on Stack Overflow...